# Using Gatling to loop through line by line in a file and send one message at a time to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, gatling

I have file that contains text something like this

```
{"content_type":"Twitter","id":"77f985b0-a30a-11e5-8791-80000bc51f65","source_id":"676656486307639298","date":"2015-12-15T06:54:12.000Z","text":"RT @kokodeikku_bot: ?????: ??,}
{"content_type":"Twitter","id":"7837a020-a30a-11e5-8791-80000bc51f65","source_id":"676656494700568576",}
{"content_type":"Twitter","id":"7838d8a0-a30a-11e5-8791-80000bc51f65","source_id":"676656507266703360",}
```

I'm unable to read each line at a time as String to a Kafka topic within the scenario, since I can't iterate over a scenario in Gatling.

Here is my code

```
class KafkaSimulation extends Simulation {

   val line = Source.fromFile(<passing locn of file>)("UTF-8").getLines.mkString("\n") // one way by reading source from file

   val br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("<passing locn of file>"))
   var line:String = ""

   while ({ line = br.readLine() ; line != null } ) {
       //In this while loop i can print line by line but i cant use while loop within scenario below  
        println(listOfLines.mkString("\n"))      
        }

  val kafkaConf = kafka

    // Kafka topic name
    .topic("test")
    // Kafka producer configs
    .properties(
      Map(
        ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG -> "1",
        // list of Kafka broker hostname and port pairs
          ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG -> "localhost:9092",
       // Required since Apache Kafka 0.8.2.0
        ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG ->
          "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer",
        ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG ->
          "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer"))

     val scn = scenario("Kafka Test")
    .exec(kafka("request") 
       // message to send 
       .send(line.toString())) //Here if i put line.toString(), it doesnt read line by line instead it will post entire 3 lines as one message

  setUp(
      scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(10) during (1 seconds)))
     .protocols(kafkaConf)

}
```

Any tips for how I can iterate over a file and read line by line in scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Turn your file into a one column CSV Feeder and use the standard Gatling way: feed a record, send your request, and repeat as much as you want.

Comment: Thanks Stephane for your quick response. It works now but there is one problem though with the line posted to Apache Kafka, it trims the first double quotes within the braces like this as {content_type": instead of sending it as {"content_type":  probably some encoding issue with the file am using. but many thanks

Comment: A Feeder is just an Iterator[Map[String, Any]]. You can easily parse you file with Source.getLines, and map those lines to turn them into a Map with one single entry.

Answer (score 0):

For this objective the only thing you really need is to open the file and iterate over it, line by line. @stephane comment was a bit raw, but what he meant is:

```
Source
  .fromFile("files/yourtargetfile.txt")
  .getLines
  .map { line =>
    //do your stuff  
  }.foreach(println)
```

Or, something simpler if you don't want to edit the contents of the file:

```
Source
  .fromFile("files/ChargeNames")
  .getLines
  .foreach { line =>
    //do your stuff 
  }
```

I hope this helps,
Cheers.